# java.lang.RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread while generating world in thread

Tags: java, multithreading, opengl, libgdx, lwjgl

Im making a 2D sandbox game(like terraria) with LibGDX. I have come across a issue though. I need the world to generated in another thread so the program can render the animated loading screen while it generates. I put the generation code in a new thread. When I run it, I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
```

Why is this happening and how can i fix it? When the generator runs it needs to create a Sprite which requires OpenGL, but it seems to not like running in a seperate thread. Any insights?

Answer (score 2):

OK solved.

Libgdx has a sweet util that can post code from a new thread into the main GL thread. Here is a example:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
     public void run(){
          //Here we are telling libgdx to connect a new runnable to the gl thread
          Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable(){
               //Type thread code here. Will be seperate to main thread but part of it at the same time
          }
     }

});
```

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is possible to somehow create a GL context in a new thread (but I'm not sure since I haven't done this ever) but **why the heck are you trying to achieve this in that way? :)**

Instead of creating new thread to load assets / generate world just render some "loading" label/animation - anything you want and start to render world when it is done.

If you are trying to load some asset you should use [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets) and it's [update](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetManager.html#update--) method to check if assets are loaded - something like

```
    AssetManager assetManager = new AssetManager();
    //load assets

    ...

    //render method

    if(assetManager.update())
    {
        //render world or even change screen to game screen
    }
    else
        //render "loading"
```

If you are trying to generate a world just slice this operation for pieces (like generating squares N x N) and have a method to do this just add some control to check if operation is finished - it can be some enum, flag, method... So assuming that you have class WorldGenerator it would be something like

```
    WorldGenerator worldGenerator;
    //generate world

    ...

    //render method

    if(WorldGenerator.isGenerated())
    {
        //render world or even change screen to game screen
    }
    else
        //render "loading"
        //make a step of generation
```

Avoid multithreading as fire - especially in Libgdx there are really not many cases that you need this and almost every time it is well handled by framework

Comment: I looked into it, and apparently its not a option with libGDX, as stated here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Threading              Great answer though, thanks :D

Comment: Also, as for why im trying to do this. The generation code freezes everything up, preventing my my "Generating World..." loading screen from animating the status bar :D